# Core Data is deleting records when app crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an app that saves a lot of data in the phone. I am using the following code:

```
- (void)datostickets:(NSString*)cod local:(NSString*)nombre{
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *ticket =[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:ticket];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(codigo = %@)", cod];
[request setPredicate:pred];
//NSManagedObject *matches = nil;
NSError *error;
NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if ([objects count] == 0) {
    NSManagedObject *nuevoticket = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [nuevoticket setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cod] forKey:@"codigo"];
    [nuevoticket setValue:self.idloc forKey:@"actividad"];
    [nuevoticket setValue:nombre forKey:@"localidad"];
    NSLog(@"GRABA: %@",cod);
} else {
    NSLog(@"VERIFICA");
    check++;
}}
```

It saves fine, but the problem happens if the app crashes (I think it only happen this way, also the app only crashes when I am manipulating the data).

When the app crashes Core Data starts acting really weird, and it deletes the recent data that I saved, but somehow some of the old data is not deleted (apparently when I change of viewController Core Data makes a commit, so this old data is not deleted).

This problem is solved when I navigate trough the app windows and it starts again if the app crashes. I know the problem is pretty weird.

**So, is there a way to solve this? maybe there is a commit statement or something like that.**

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you certain you are saving your data successfully? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/save:

Comment: If the app does not crash, the data remains even if I turn the phone off or I close the app.

Comment: @atrik The data remains when the phone is 'off' or the app is closed because the app is still active. If you create or change NSManagedObjects without using 'save' they will persist until the app is made inactive by iOS stopping it when it is in the background or the phone is shut down (not just 'off') or at a crash. Use save whenever you have finished a set of related changes to avoid this - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [context save:&error] to commit changes.

Answer (score 0):

Use  context save& error .or if you using magicall records use MR_Save to persistent store and wait method other wise it is Unable to delete data from storage.